# Preventing cookie spoofing

Tags: java, security, cookies, jwt, spoofing

I have a JWT I've encrypted and would like to store in a HttpOnly secure cookie & send over SSL. But since I don't have the cookie set up when my site is first visited, what's to stop someone from creating a cookie with the same name & value as the cookie I want to create before I create my cookie? Basically, what if they spoof the cookie before login, which is when I actually create my cookie?

It seems like I would have to ensure my cookie always gets created first somehow to prevent this since Httponly would be what stops this which doesn't take effect until I create my cookie, right? Is there something I'm missing to prevent/circumvent this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone can spoof a JWT this mean that your secret used to sign thoses token have been compromised. There is no solution to work around this but to change your secret.

Otherwise if a cookie exists with data that can't be verified then you reject the cookie (remove it) and don't proceed with the request (return 401 status for example).

Comment: Decrypting and reading the JWT isn't my main concern. I'm not sure how I should be verifying the cookie itself is untouched as I can only get the cookie's name and value from HttpRequest in Servlet API per spec. I'm not seeing how I can verify the cookie content if it looks like it was well constructed, but is being spoofed.

Comment: Just check the content. That is your jwt token.